# Usage of dash, grammar

Tags: grammar, british-english, dashes

There are two sentences :

1. Cat is  a small animal with soft fur that people often keep as a pet.
2. Cat —  a small animal with soft fur that people often keep as a pet.

Is the second one correct from the point of view of British English Grammar? Can I use dash in this situation?

Comment: In what context? (1) is wrong since "cat" is missing an article.

Comment: I suggest  *The cat is a small animal with soft fur that people often keep as a pet or alarm clock.*

Comment: Thank you! The main question is can I use dash instead of is in such situations? A cat - a small animal with soft fur. An apple - a round fruit. In dictionaries they just write a word and it's description below. How should I do if I want to describe different things? Can I do just like they do in dictionaries? Like this :        Cat                                                                               
                                                     an animal with claws and fur.

Comment: @Jess3032 Are you writing a dictionary? What's the context?

Comment: You mixed it up. #1 needs **A cat**, not #2.

Comment: #2 isn't a sentence. It might be an acceptable in contexts where you don't need full sentences, such as PowerPoint slides.

Comment: This might be better for ELL.

Comment: It's not suitable for ELL without more explanation of what the context is. What's OK in a label/notice, advertisement, or informal note is not necessarily OK in an academic paper or newspaper article.

Answer (score 2):

You can use dashes before and after to separate a definition from the rest of some text. For example

> A cat — a small animal with soft fur that people often keep as a pet — was seen crouching behind a tree.

If you are just providing a list of definitions I would suggest colons. If you want your definition to be a complete sentence you would need to slightly adapt your first example by putting "a" or "the" at the beginning, for example

> A cat is a small animal with soft fur that people often keep as a pet.